# Tabs content just disappear when clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, tabs

I'm trying to build a menu with jQuery with changing content with tabs but when I click a different `<li>` item the content just disappears. I'm using the list items to change the content below.

Sorry there´s some images missing on the menu items but I think you can get the idea.

The first content is there, but when I want to change it all is gone.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('ul li').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $('ul li').attr('data-tab');

    $('ul li').removeClass('active');
    $('.content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
  });

});
```

```css
/* ASIDE */


/* NAV */

aside {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

aside nav {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

aside nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

aside nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 6px 6px 12px 6px;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}

aside nav ul li img {
  display: block;
  width: 1.1rem;
  height: 1.1rem;
  margin: 4px auto;
}

aside div {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}

.content.current {
  display: inline-block;
}

aside .content img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

aside .content label {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.content p {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="tabs" role="navigation" aria-label="menu">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li tabindex="1" data-tab="tab-1"><img src="img/figures.svg" alt="figures selector">Figures</li>
    <li tabindex="2" data-tab="tab-2"><img src="img/references.svg" alt="references selector">References</li>
    <li tabindex="3" data-tab="tab-3"><img src="img/related.svg" alt="related selector">Related</li>
    <li tabindex="4" data-tab="tab-4"><img src="img/info.svg" alt="details selector">Details</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<!-- CONTENT -->
<div id="tab-1" role="content" aria-label="figures content" class="content current">
  <img src="img/figure1.jpg" alt="figure 1" id="fig1" value="fig1">
  <label for="fig1">Fig. 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</label>
  <hr/>
  <img src="img/figure2.png" alt="figure 2" id="fig2" value="fig2">
  <label for="fig2">Fig. 2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</label>
  <hr/>
  <img src="img/figure3.png" alt="figure 3" id="fig3" value="fig3">
  <label for="fig3">Fig. 3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</label>
  <hr/>
</div>
<div id="tab-2" role="content" aria-label="references content" class="content">
  <h3>Lorem</h3>
  <hr>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <h3>Lorem</h3>
  <hr>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
</aside>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `data-tab` attribute from the currently clicked `li` element. So it should be:

```
var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
```